# Deleted documents of local clients are not reflecting in remote server after replication

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have written my own JavaScript based CouchDB replication client.

I have a doc at my local client which, I have deleted.
`{"_id":"5ebe99c6b179d0be4ff05bd43d0038d1","_deleted":true,"_rev":"2-c6667ac72ec89a03496f6e402265a2eba6a1d695"}`

I make a bulk doc request to push it to couchdb server. I get empty array as response.
I check on remote couchdb server using `/{db}/doc_id?rev=deleted_doc_rev`, and its present there too.

However I still see the doc at remote server, in spite of the fact that the doc is deleted and is replicated too.

Comment: How are you verifying the existence of the doc on the remote server?

Comment: @Flimzy I used a request like this : **/{db}/doc_id?rev=deleted_doc_rev** to check if my version of the doc is pushed to remote server. I have resolved the issue. The problem was of MVCC. If the remote and local doc do not have same branches of MVCC this issue occurs. My Document was avalable on remte server but on a different branch, other then the one CouchDB consider as Current visible branch in its MVCC storage. MY replicator avoided implementing MVCC, which I did now and issue is resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Ok Guys,

The problem was in my replicator.I created my replicator without considering MVCC structure of CouchDB. In the replication protocol while making bulk request one need to send the MVCC structure present locally to server, to override the current branch at the server(couchdb).

Previously my bulk reqeust would be like:

```
POST http://0.0.0.0:5984/{db}/_bulk_docs

{
  "docs" : [ {
    "_id" : "5ebe99c6b179d0be4ff05bd43d0038d1",
    "_deleted" : true,
    "_rev" : "2-c6667ac72ec89a03496f6e402265a2eba6a1d695"
  } ],
  "new_edits" : false
}
```

However for getting the correct MVCC based replication, one need to make bulk request like this:

```
POST http://0.0.0.0:5984/{db}/_bulk_docs

{
  "docs" : [ {
    "_deleted" : true,
    "_id" : "5ebe99c6b179d0be4ff05bd43d0038d1",
    "_rev" : "2-7a5de99d17a4504b2f74cda829bf7054",
    "_revisions" : {
      "start" : 2,
      "ids" : [ "7a5de99d17a4504b2f74cda829bf7054", "0c4f4e08acc7931c290193b1434f5e2b" ]
    }
  } ],
  "new_edits" : false
}
```

I figured this by studying traffic between correct replicator implementations.